# How to change image size and change next/prev image using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox, wordpress

I want to develop a light box plugin so i created some css and made this script below

```
$(function (){
   $("img").click(function() {
   var imp = $(this).attr('src');
   var i=700;
   var j=700;
   $(".box").html($("<img>").attr("width", i));
   $(".box").html($("<img>").attr("width", j));
   $(".box").html($("<img>").attr("src", imp));


  });
});


css

.box
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:20%;
            left:20%;
            width:auto;
            height:auto;
            background:#ffffff;
            z-index:999999;
            padding:10px;
            box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
            display:none;
        }
```

Here **.box** is the class div in which i'm showing the image when a user clicks it.but i want to show it in big, so i used **width** attr but its not changing for me. also  i want to add next previous functionality to change the images to next image when the user clicks next and prev. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function (){
    $("img").click(function() {
    var imp = $(this).attr('src');
    var i=700;
    var j=700;
    $img=$("<img>");
    $(".box").html($img);
    $img.width(i);
    $img.attr('src',imp);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ya working.How can i move to next image with next button clicked, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use **[prettyPhoto(a jQuery lightbox clone)](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto)** if you want to reduce your job.

you will get the code for lightbox as well as its gallery.

If you are looking for simple light box then use a modalmask having `$("body").height()`
    and `$("body").width()`,`z-index:5001` and `opacity:0.3` .Then change the css of box in such a way that it gets aligned to page in center,increase the z-index of `.box` to 5001 and append image inside it.